# Is is possible to sign a binary via .NET code? (no signtool.exe)

Tags: .net, certificate

I've the following requirement, sign a binary with a certificate, but without signtool.exe; the idea would be to do it via code.

Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692565/how-do-you-programmatically-resign-a-net-assembly-with-a-strong-name

Comment: Indeed. thanks for spotting this. That said, how shall I proceed? delete this question, or leave it open as it's not asked the same way?

Comment: Not a duplicate. `signtool.exe` (referenced here) generates Authenticode signatures (for any PE file); "strong naming" (mentioned in the other question) uses `sn.exe` and is for managed assemblies only.

Comment: I think you can leave it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the [SignerSign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387733.aspx) or [SignerSignEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387734.aspx) functions that are exported from mssign32.dll.

To use these, you'll need to define managed versions of the `SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO`,  `SIGNER_FILE_INFO`, `SIGNER_CERT`, `SIGNER_SIGNATURE_INFO`, etc. structs, then correctly specify the P/Invoke signature for the native method.

Halfway through [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/12/11/how-to-sign-exe-files-with-an-authenticode-certificate-part-2.aspx), there is a C++ example of calling `SignerSignEx`; [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187030/mark) has ported it to C# in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357759/has-anyone-got-any-code-to-call-signersignex-from-c).

Comment: Didn't get it working in C# (didn't spend enought time, was on a very short deadline), but it worked perfectly in good old C++. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Windows 8, use signerSignEx2